# CSS - Display grid expand columns, when no "neighbor" element

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to understand why I can't make this work. Right now, I'm using display grid and using grid-row to determine a element position and length (span). It works, but when no other columns shares the same slot (row) I want the element to expand to fill all the columns.

[image]
Ari's should be expanded since no other element shares the same slot.

Example of HTML for Rosenval's:

```
<div class="event" style="--color: #b10dc9; grid-row: 3 / span 2;">[...]</div>
```

It starts on row 3 and expands 2.

```
.grid {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(0, 0, 0 / .1);

    flex: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(27, 56px); /* Rows for time slots */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(1fr, auto));

    overflow: hidden;

    & div {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```